# Percentage Increase/Decrease in SUM between 2 dates where first SUM is zero

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query like this -

```
SELECT location, 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0)) AS previous, 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-12-31',1,0)) AS current, 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-12-31',1,0))- 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0)) as diff, ( 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-12-31',1,0))- 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0)))/ 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0))*100 AS percent 
FROM table group by location order by percent DESC
```

which I based on previous answers found on stackoverflow.

The idea is to return a location, a previous date range count, a current count (these ranges change), the numeric difference between previous and current and the % increase or decrease.

Something like -

```
LOCATION 1     38    27    -11    -28.94%
LOCATION 2     6     18     12    200.00%
```

etc

The code above, while probably clunky, seems to work, EXCEPT when the PREVIOUS count is found to be zero, then percent is returned as NULL, instead of the increase/decrease.

ie

```
LOCATION 3     0     32      32     (NULL)
```

Can anyone advise how to alter the query to resolve this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your previous value equals to 0 it would cause a division by zero on your percentage column.

> By default, division by zero produces a result of NULL and no warning.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-expressions.html

Since you have a division by zero I am not sure if it would make any sense to replace the NULL value for any other but you should be able to replace it by checking for a zero at the previous count before making the division.

Example (replacing it with zero):

```
SELECT location, 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0)) AS previous, 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-12-31',1,0)) AS current, 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-12-31',1,0))- 
SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0)) as diff, ( 
case 
  when (SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0))) then
    0
  else
    SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-12-31',1,0))- 
    SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0)))/ 
    SUM(IF(action_dt_tm BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30',1,0))*100
end
 AS percent 
FROM table group by location order by percent DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. But doesnt that mean that for calculations where the previous value is 0, it will just return 0 instead of calculating an increase?

Comment: It would. I just gave you an example to show you could use to replace the value.
You would need to check what would make sense for a replacement.

Comment: I take your point and it does give me a starting point, thanks.  I just have to work out an alternative formula now